# node authentication model / scheme

Tags: javascript, security, authentication, node.js

(xposted from nodejs@googlegroups.com)

what's the best locally stored authentication scheme?

i've found a few:

- http://dailyjs.com/2011/01/10/node-tutorial-9/
- github.com/ncb000gt/node.bcrypt.js/tree/master/examples
- github.com/Turbo87/locomotive-passport-boilerplate/blob/master/app/models/account.js
  (which looks like it came from the bcrypt example)

it looks like mongoose-auth implement from bcrypt's example as well:

- github.com/bnoguchi/mongoose-auth/blob/master/lib/modules/password/plugin.js

and, i can't figure out how everyauth is generating passwords.

- github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth/blob/master/lib/modules/password.js

... and i've found tons that generate based on Math.random(Date.now *
some_number).... something like that - didn't look right so i don't
exactly remember.

what's the best method for doing this security wise?

Answer (score 0):

Locally storing authenticated credentials is one of the worst possible ways to authenticate clients.  In order to pull this off you need to use cryptography,  which introduces the possibility of brute force.   A good example of how this goes horribly wrong is the [Oracle Padding Attack used against .Net](http://threatpost.com/en_us/blogs/demo-aspnet-padding-oracle-attack-091710).

If you want a secure system you won't implement this.  If you want something that isn't very secure but probably will work then you should use an [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC).  Bcrypt, block ciphers,  and stream ciphers are really not the right choice.  You can implement an HMAC with bcrypt,  but i would choose another hash function like sha256.

Also,  the current date time is **NOT A RANDOM VALUE**,  this should never be relayed upon for the calculation for a random value.  You will need to keep track of the time so that the session token can expire.  Your secret should be generated with an entropy store like `/dev/random`

Comment: The date is being used for the seed for the random number. Also, wrt /dev/random, I have been told reading this directly lowers the randomness and that /dev/urandom should be used instead. That said, I'm looking at HMAC that you recommended to see if there's something I missed or a better way of authenticating (I think my client would prefer ldap or ad but those modules seem experiment

Comment: s/experiment/to be quite beta and I don't want to support this yet)./